# How to do UIKIT nav accordion always open?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, uikit

I make a sidebar with UIKIT Nav component.

http://getuikit.com/docs/nav.html

That could be able to make accordion like this.

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-side uk-nav-parent-icon" data-uk-nav="{multiple:true}">
    <li class="uk-parent">
        <a href="#">parrent</a>
        <ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-side">
            <li class="uk-active">
                <a href="#">current</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">not current</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If I click accordion menu. Tag will change it.

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-side uk-nav-parent-icon" data-uk-nav="{multiple:true}">
    <li class="uk-parent uk-open" aria-expanded="true">
        <a href="#">parent</a>
        <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
            <ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-side">
                <li class="uk-active">
                    <a href="#">current</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">not current</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If I do page reload, All accordion will close.

So what do I wanna ask you the question is how to always open when the request-url is current?
I wanna always open the parent ul tag that nest class uk-active li tag.

I think that will be able with jQuery or PHP.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to reply this too late.

Finally, I understand always open trigger is 'uk-active' class.

There are no relation with 'uk-open', aria-expanded="true" or div bla bla bla.

Just set 'uk-active' class on element you wanna always show it.
So, This is my solution.

http://codepen.io/qwe001/pen/JKgBBx

And ya, Need to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to set uk-active class.
Btw, I use php framework Laravel5. So my code is like this.

```
<div class="uk-width-medium">
    <div class="uk-panel uk-panel-box">
        <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-side uk-nav-parent-icon" data-uk-nav="{multiple:true}">
            <li class="uk-parent {{ Request::is('admin/parent1*') ? 'uk-active' : '' }}">
                <a href="#">Parent 1 (Have Nest and Nest is current)</a>
                <ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-side">
                    <li class="{{ Request::is('admin/parent1/nest1*') ? 'uk-active' : '' }}">
                        <a href="/admin/parent1/nest1">Nest 1 (current)</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{ Request::is('admin/parent1/nest2*') ? 'uk-active' : '' }}">
                        <a href="/admin/parent1/nest2">Nest 2 (not current)</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="{{ Request::is('admin/parent1/nest3*') ? 'uk-active' : '' }}">
                        <a href="/admin/parent1/nest3">Nest 3 (not current)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="{{ Request::is('admin/parent2*') ? 'uk-active' : '' }}">
                <a href="/admin/parent2">Parent 2 (Not Nest)</a>
            </li>
            <li class="uk-parent {{ Request::is('admin/parent3*') ? 'uk-active' : '' }}">
                <a href="#">Parent 3 (Have Nest but Current nests are nothing)</a>
                <ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-side">
                    <li class="{{ Request::is('admin/parent3/nest1*') ? 'uk-active' : '' }}">
                        <a href="/admin/parent3/nest1">Nest 1 (not current)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: Must need adjust parent uk-parent class color like this.

```
/* Adjust Parent Background Color */
.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent.uk-active > a {
    background: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}

.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent.uk-active > a:hover,
.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent.uk-active > a:focus {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #444;
    outline: none;
}

/* Adjust Parent Child Padding */
.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent .uk-nav-side > li > a {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.uk-nav-side > li.uk-parent .uk-nav-side > li.uk-active > a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: i am using a nested scenario, but in case it helps anyone else, i had to use `uk-open` and not `uk-active`, like this `<li class="uk-parent uk-open">`

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your another code, but a way is this:

Your url: index.php?id=2

```
<?php
$page = (isset($_GET['id']))?(int)$_GET['id']:'';
?>
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-side uk-nav-parent-icon" data-uk-nav="{multiple:true}">
   <li class="uk-parent">
        <a href="#">parrent</a>
        <ul class="uk-nav-sub uk-nav-side">
            <li class="<?=(($page==2)?'uk-active':'')?>">
                <a href="#">current</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">not current</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code:

```
<?=(($page==2)?'uk-active':'')?>
```

is the short notation of this:

```
<?php 
if($page == 2){
   echo "uk-active";
}else{
   echo "";
}
```